# How to do GridSearchCV with multi-metric evaluation for "expensive" predict calls

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a custom instance-based estimator with "expensive" predict calls, which I want to pass to `GridSearchCV` and have it calculate multiple metrics as is possible since Version 19.0 and described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-multi-metric-evaluation-py). This was implemented to avoid calling `train` multiple times. For me prediction is more expensive than training, and within the scorer `predict` is still called on the estimator for each scorer [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L101), even though it would suffice to only calculate `y_pred` once and simply pass it to the `_score_func` for each metric:

```
class _PredictScorer(_BaseScorer):
    def __call__(self, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight=None):
        [...]
        y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
        [...]
        return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,
                                                 **self._kwargs)
```

Even if rolling my one Scorer and inheriting from _BaseScorer, I see no way to include y_pred, as it is called within GridSearchCV something like:

```
score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
```

I could write my own grid search, but like the interface, so that it could easily be exchanged with other classes such as RandomSearchCV or possibly more complex classes in the future. Also, I like working with the cv_results_ data frame.

I could also cache calls with the same parameters within the estimator which feels hacky.

Any other ways this could be achieved using as much of sklearn API?

Comment: If you can wrap your estimator in a Pipeline, then the `'memory'` param may help caching the calls. See [Pipeline documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). But without looking at your complete code, its hard to say.